# set background for itemView programmatically

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to set the background of a `ViewHolder` `Holder.itemView` by `holder.itemView.setBackground('someKindofDrawable')`.

I used gradient to create it but it doesn't give the expected result.
i need to create a simple lightweight component for the background.

this is the code i use:

```
GradientDrawable gradientRectangle = new GradientDrawable(
                Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[]{0xFFFFFFFF,0x00000000});

gradientRectangle.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE); 

holder.itemView.setBackground(gradientRectangle);
```

the image is the expected result (the boarders represent the rectangle).

[image: expected result]

Comment: Why don't you use `Relative Layout` as parent and an `ImageView` with both height and width as `match_parent` and set Image resource to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer (if it helps anyone):

```
public class DrawableItemSelectedBackgroundITopColor
{
    LayerDrawable layerdrawable;
    Drawable[] DrawableArray;

    ColorDrawable topColor;
    ColorDrawable bottomColor;

    public DrawableItemSelectedBackgroundITopColor(Context context, String Theme)
    {

        topColor = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.tiny_prints_blue));
        bottomColor = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));

        DrawableArray = new Drawable[]{
                topColor,
                bottomColor
        };

        layerdrawable = new LayerDrawable(DrawableArray);

        layerdrawable.setLayerInset(0,0,0,0,0);
        layerdrawable.setLayerInset(1,0,9,0,0);
    }

    public LayerDrawable getDrawableBackgroundItemTop(){
        return layerdrawable;
    }
}
```